# HTML: Trying to send position of a drop down box AND contents of input box on button press

Tags: html

I should start by saying I am *not* an HTML programmer. I'm trying to create what should be a simple HTML page for an embedded server I'm working on and creating with embedded C.

I've successfully populated a very large HTML drop-down box with over one hundred entries and sent what is selected by the drop down box when a button is pressed. This seems to work OK. I'm doing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset>
<select name="TileID"><option value="0">+61.22-KC-E02-E01<option value="1">+61.22-KC-E02-E02<option value="2">+61.22-KC-E02-E03

etc etc etc

<input type="submit" name="on" value="Switch Tile On">
</fieldset>
</form>Control the lights on the DALI buses <br> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

The drop down box, as I said, has over 100 entires in it.

With this, I send back a No Content from the embedded server to the broswer and it seems happy.

What I need to do is add a text box so I can add light level to set a light to. I've tried all sorts of things such as adding:

```
<input type="text" name="level" value="% Level">
```

Changing `<form>` to:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

But nothing works. Various things either just don't work or I get a timeout when the button is pressed.

I got the impression what I wanted to do should be quite simple, but I'm going round in circles now! Would be most grateful if someone could point out where I'm goign wrong and what I need to do.

Comment: The input in itself looks trivial, so the problem must be in the server that processes this request.

Comment: Is your server equipped to handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding?

Comment: The server is what I'm writing  in C. It's essentially capable of handling anything I program it to do. I doubt very much it's the server though, it's surely the HTML that's in the browser that's incorrect and I need the correct syntax for?

Comment: There is no syntax error in that input that could cause this. The problem is in the server. Unless your own custom written C program is perfect and you accidentally have downloaded a browser that happens to hang on any form that contains an input, of course.

Comment: But why does it work when only sending the value of the drop down box? What could possibly be different in the server (or needed in the server) when it receives two values? In both case I'm returning a No Content reply.